# Format number if the function returned a number and its a float

Tags: ruby

```
my_number = get_salary_range(user)
```

Right now my method may return 324234.23424222

I want it to be:

2342343.23

(two decimal places)

But I have to gaurd against the return value being nil, or '' etc.

How can I do this safely?

Comment: "1234552.99" is the number I want

Answer (score 5):

The solution depends on what you want in your string when `my_number.nil?` is true. Forcibly converting things to Float would be a reasonable starting point:

```
formatted_number = '%.2f' % my_number.to_f
```

That will handle the expected numeric `my_number` values as well as `nil`, `"nonsense"`, and `''` (with the latter three producing `0.00`).

If you want to more thorough, then you can ask your `my_number` if it understands `to_f`:

```
formatted_number = '%.2f' % (my_number.respond_to?(:to_f) ? my_number.to_f : 0.0)
```

But you're still left to decide what should happen if `my_number` cannot be sensibly converted to a Float.

You can go one step further and make the "what about things that aren't Float-ish" configurable:

```
def numberify(thing, default = "0.00")
    return thing.respond_to?(:to_f) \
         ? '%.2f' % thing.to_f \
         : default
end
```

Further configurability is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I have to think about it, but either '' or 0.